# Nat with saving real client IP

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I have this schema:
**Client** -> **NAT server** -> **Game server**

On NAT server I have the following rules:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -d $MC_IP -p tcp --dport 25550:25580 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $SRV_IP -p tcp --dport 25550:25580 -j DNAT --to-destination $MC_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25550:25580 -o eth0 -d $MC_IP -j SNAT --to-source $SRV_IP
```

What is the problem:
This rules works fine, but every user have *NAT serve IP*, but I need to get the real user IP.

Answer (score 0):

As you can easily read on wikipedia, [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) is a technique to manipulate IP address to "hide" for some reason the original ones.

If you do not want to hide your addresses, do not use NAT.